# How to apply Domain Driven Design Principles, while designing a generic system?

Tags: domain-driven-design

So, Lets say we have to design an Library Management System. Now, this could be done by domain driven design principles by writing a ubiquitous Language, then figuring out the bounded contexts, creating the Aggregate roots and finally having a object model with Books, Users, Authors etc.

But, what if we have to design a generic system something on lines of Salesforce or Sharepoint ( With capabilities to design and create custom forms and workflows). So, first we will create a generic system, which can be used to implement library management system or any other system like human resource management system or something.

Can we still apply the Domain Driven Design principles in designing the Generic System ? If, Yes, then in ubiquitous Language should we list domain objects like Books, Users, Authors, Employees, Departments etc or  should we just list the Generic objects/Name Value pair/Hashtable. Since, This generic system could be used to implement any other domain specific system.

In other words how to apply domain driven design principles in creating a generic system? Which could be used to for implement other domain specific systems later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can we still apply the Domain Driven Design principles in designing
>   the Generic System?

Yes, DDD can be applied to the generic system you describe.

> If, Yes, then in ubiquitous Language should we list domain objects
>   like Books, Users, Authors, Employees, Departments etc or should we
>   just list the Generic objects/Name Value pair/Hashtable.

Names such as **object** and **hashtable** are not only generic, but also have very strong technical connotations. The ubiquitous language is to be shared among developers and domain experts and should therefore have as little technical implications as possible. This is not to say that a technical name such as **object** is the wrong name - just be aware of the distinction between your domain and the supporting technical infrastructure. Even if all domain experts are developers, making this distinction is important.

It can be said that DDD consists of two components - tactical and strategic. The tactical patterns are of a technical nature and include things such as repositories, value objects, etc. These patterns usually have specific manifestations for each language and platform. These patterns are also most likely to change as technology changes. For example, if when using [event-sourcing](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html) with DDD, the tactical patterns are somewhat different. In implementing a generic system such as the one you describe the tactical patterns may be different yet again.

The strategic patterns operate at a higher level of abstraction and include things like bounded contexts, context maps, the ubiquitous language, model/design whirlpool. These patterns aren't bound by technical constraints and are applicable outside of the tactical patterns. They are also, in a sense, more important than the tactical patterns and are applicable regardless of the underlying technology because they are tailored more towards the way people think than the way computers do. As a result, you can still reap the benefits of the strategic patterns in a generic domain.

Comment: But the question is that in case when you are designing a generic system, What would you put in ubiquitous language. There is no domain your targeting.

Comment: There is always a domain, in this case it just happens to be a generic/abstract/technical one. You can put terms that may be generic in the ubiquitous language, but they don't have to have technical implications, such as the term hashtable does.

Comment: So you mean you can use words like PrimaryEntity, ChildEntity or GenericResource or something like that to represent a generic entity. But, one should not be using Hashtable or Arraylist as these are technology specifc..

Comment: Yes. One of the goals of DDD with the ubiquitous language is to distill the core aspects of your domain as pure knowledge with as little technical connotation as possible. This facilitates reasoning about the domain as well as facilitating communication. Overall, it's a subtle shift in thinking, but it pays dividends.

Comment: I have though of the same thing, however it still bugs me that domain users will use different names/aliases for these objects depending on the business it's used in. They will see the difference in terms as technical naming even though it's linked to logical abstraction and not technical terms. This will happen probably when a discussion between the technical and domain teams takes place. which is still against the ubiquitous language idea. Kind of paradoxical on this part.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with some of the notes @eulerfx said. In the generic domain, you still have meanings for the objects. In fact, when you use a generic domain, the words must represent much more than a specific domain. For example, ChildEntity is not a good name because the abstraction is too high and it doesn't add any meaning to your object. You should consider the object's actions and properties coherence to choose a name for the object.

Assume you want to design a sales domain as generic. In your system, you have multiple types of people. Customer and Seller for example. In your sales domain, you don't need those, and you refer to any person as an account entity. It's hard to abstract the names to make it generic and it's one of the generic domains hardships. All clients must be able to map their UL concepts to your generic domain UL concepts. Otherwise, your design is not generic enough.